# How do I consume Get-Content in a PowerShell cmdlet?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, powershell

The question is for a `PowerShell 3.0` `cmdlet` using `C#` in `.Net Framework 4.0` in `Visual Studio 2010`.

We're writing a PowerShell cmdlet that needs input from the pipeline. Like...

```
Get-Content .\somefile.bin -Encoding Byte | Receive-Bytes
```

The Receive-Bytes cmdlet needs to work the same way Set-Content works. Like...

```
Get-Content .\somefile.bin -Encoding Byte | Set-Content otherfile.bin -Encoding Byte
```

We have tried the following three options:

```
[System.Management.Automation.Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
public byte Input { private get; set; }
public byte[] Input { private get; set; }
public System.IO.BinaryReader Input { private get; set; }
```

But... byte, byte[], BinaryReader all result in the same error.

```
+ Get-Content .\somefile.bin | Receive-Bytes
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: [Receive-Bytes], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 

Receive-Bytes : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
```

We noticed that the error repeats several times, suggesting Get-Content was actually sending several chunks of data. Researched and found that to be the case ( http://brianreiter.org/2010/01/29/powershells-object-pipeline-corrupts-piped-binary-data/ ) but that puts us no closer to solving it.

So... The question is: how do we setup a System.Management.Automation.Parameter to accept a byte stream sent from Get-Content?

Update: Answers below point to using -Encoding Byte on Get-Content, and within Receive-Bytes using...

```
public IConvertible Input { private get; set; }
```

IConvertible gets the data in. But what we get in Receive-Bytes doesn't match the source file we select with Get-Content.

So... How do we setup the parameter to change IConvertible back to a byte stream?

Comment: Did you try `Get-Content .\somefile.bin -Encoding byte` ?